# range error in gridview.builder i'm getting range error in gridview.builder i also have data in list but its still showing only 8

Tags: flutter, dart

i am creating a gridview with list of collage i have 20 collages list but it is showing only 8 i dont know why i have tried many thins but still getting this range error i am creating a gridview with list of collage i have 20 collages list but it is showing only 8 i dont know why i have tried many thins but still getting this range error

```
GridView.builder(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: MediaQuery.of(context).orientation ==
                        Orientation.landscape
                    ? 3
                    : 2,
                crossAxisSpacing: 8,
                mainAxisSpacing: 8,
                childAspectRatio: (2 / 1),
              ),
              itemCount: universityListTitle.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                        12,
                      ),
                      color: containerColors[index]
                     .withOpacity(1.0),
                      ),
                  child: Center(
                      child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          universityListTitle[index],
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 13,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        univerSityListSubtitle[index],
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 13,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )),
                );
              },
            ),
```

[image]

Comment: universityListTitle is a list and grid view's item count is universityListTitle.length. Then, what's that univerSityListSubtitle came from? in your Text Widget ? May be universityListSubtitle is another list.

Comment: I think "univerSityListSubtitle[index]" is the problem here. because you use universityListTitle as a length if the length of univerSityListSubtitle is not matched it'll sure be error

Comment: yes that is another list now i removed the univerSityListSubtitle but still getting error

Answer (score 0):

There are two different Lists with different Lengths.

1. `universityListTitle`
2. `univerSityListSubtitle`

one of them isn't matching the specified amount in

```
 itemCount: universityListTitle.length
```

(Which builds mentioned amount of widgets based on the item count so..)

To fix this, The professional and Nice approach is creating a Model by using `classes` of properties you want in your List.

```
class University {
  final String? universityName; // universityListTitle
  final String? universityLabel; // universityListSubTitle
  University({this.universityLabel, this.universityName});
}
```

then a sample List:

```
List<University> universityList = [
    University(
        universityLabel: 'Your carrer is ruined here! :D',
        universityName: 'Ruined University'),
    University(
        universityLabel: 'Your carrer is created here! :p',
        universityName: 'Productive University'),
    University(
        universityLabel: 'Your carrer is eaten here! :0',
        universityName: 'Corrupted University'),
  ];
```

and then to fit it with your code and access it by `Text(universityList[index].universityName)`